# Meaning of 'conciergerie vélos'

Tags: sens

Talking about the old status of an enterprise I heard the turn

> conciergerie vélos

Googling did not help me to figure out what is its meaning.

Comment: Interesting term; where does it come from?

Comment: @anonymous2 See my attempt to answer my question:-)! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Dimitris what kind of company? In a vacuum, "Bike valet" looks like a good equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concierge était jadis une charge prestigieuse : ([cnrtl](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/concierge))

> Celui qui a la charge d'un édifice important (château, palais), d'un établissement  public.

Dans l'usage courant, le terme s'est ensuite semble-t-il banalisé pour désigner simplement un gardien d'immeuble :

> Celui, celle qui, dans certains établissements publics ou immeubles particuliers, est chargé(e) de surveiller l'entrée, de renseigner les visiteurs, de distribuer le courrier, d'entretenir les parties communes, etc.

Plus récemment, cependant, les termes concierge et conciergerie ont regagné en popularité sur un mode un peu plus haut-de-gamme évoquant le concierge de grand hôtel.

On voit notamment les conciergeries d'entreprise déjà citées, mais aussi des services de conciergerie [fournies avec certaines cartes bancaire](https://www.lefigaro.fr/conso/2007/01/08/05007-20070108ARTWWW90470-les_caprices_les_plus_fous_des_porteurs_de_cartes_bancaires.php)s, ou encore les [services de conciergerie AirBnb](https://www.allovoyages.fr/mag/conciergerie-airbnb-paris/) qui se proposent de gérer certains aspect de la location entre particulier (accueil, remise des clés etc.) à la place des propriétaires ("hôtes").

[image]

Pour répondre plus précisément sur la conciergerie vélo, ça semble être un nouvel avatar des conciergeries récente toujours vendu à l'utilisateur/client selon la promesse : "on s'occupe de tout", cette fois appliqué au vélo.

A noter enfin que la [conciergerie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conciergerie) est aussi le nom d'un célébre bâtiment historique de Paris ayant servi de prison pendant plusieurs siècles.

Answer (score 1):

I post an answer. Feel free to edit it or add another answer.

> (...)
>
> 3. Service d’un grand hôtel, génér. attenant à la réception, chargé de veiller au bon déroulement du séjour des clients (accueil, conseils, renseignements) et de satisfaire leurs demandes (réservation de billets, location de voiture, etc.).
> 4. Par extension. Service proposé à des particuliers (conciergerie privée) ou à des salariés (conciergerie d’entreprise), sur le modèle
>    d’une conciergerie d’hôtel, offrant une gamme de prestations
>    personnalisées visant à leur faciliter la vie au quotidien.

Source: https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/conciergerie/17921

I think that conciergerie vélos offers some kind of service concerning the bicycle. For instance googling provided the following result

> Conciergerie à vélos
>
> Confiez-nous votre vélo, nous nous occupons de tout ! Notre équipe de
> mécaniciens déplace l’atelier de mécanique au pied de votre entreprise
> pour réparer les vélos des collaborateurs pendant qu’ils travaillent.
> Conciergerie à vélos : Confiez-nous votre vélo, nous nous occupons de
> tout ! Notre équipe de mécaniciens déplace l’atelier de mécanique au
> pied de votre entreprise pour réparer les vélos des collaborateurs
> pendant qu’ils travaillent.

Comment: The explanation seems pretty clear to me. On which aspect do you expect a more thourough explanation?

Comment: @XouDo I do not know to be honest. I added for the sake of modesty -)!

Comment: So I tried to dig a little more ;-)